# How to retrieve a number (ID) inside a image path using js/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the sample path, assuming the format is fixed

For the 4th image, the path is '`demo/medium/Web081112_P004_medium.jpg`'

so if the image is the 100 th ,then

'`demo/medium/Web081112_P100_medium.jpg` '

Is there any way to get the number in this format, I have thought about using reg exp? But it may cause a problem because I may retrieve 004 instead of 4, how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: var num = parseInt(path.split("_P")[1],10)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is based on the message in the original question

*sample path, assuming the format is fixed*

If the string is not going to change then you can use split:

```
var num = parseInt(path.split("_P")[1],10);
```

**Note** remember the parseInt needs the radix 10 to remove the leading 0s which would otherwise make the number OCTAL

Also note that splitting on `_P` will (as mentioned by  Cerbrus) get the the string `004_medium.jpg` which still works with parseInt because parseInt will ignore trailing non-numeric characters

Comment: Thanks :) I posted as a comment, but then decided to make it an answer seeing the regex suggestion :)

Comment: Yeah, i up voted your comment as well, when i saw that one long before the answer.

Comment: problem with this is, there is no implicit "pattern match", where you can dictate *how the input has to look like*. Beside that, good answer.

Comment: Hence the disclaimer at the top - the answer was based on OPs description _assuming the format is fixed_

Comment: Really appreciate,  better than my original thought

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thats <strike>definitely</strike>probably regular expression work.

```
/.*?\/.*?\/.*?_P(\d+).*?/.exec( imagesource )[ 1 ];
```

That way, you can have a "strict" pattern definition where you only parse that number if the input string has a certain format. You can write it more sloppy, like suggested in the comments

```
/.*?_P(\d+)/.exec( imagesource )[ 1 ];
```

<sup>*disclaimer*: I'm not that regexp genius, so please comment any optimizations :P</sup>

Comment: I'd say you can (and should) omit the `.*?` in the beginning and end - the regex does not need to match the whole string (without the `^` and `$` anchors). Maybe even the whole slash-matching is not needed (to make it the same as @mplungjan's split), but that's a decision of accuracy

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex, this will get a `int` from between the first and second occurrence of `"_"`.

```
var path = 'demo/medium/Web081112_P100_medium.jpg'
var id = ~~path.split('_')[1].substr(1);
```

Remove the `.substr(1)` in case the `"P"` prefix is removed.

I'm using the `~~` as a quick-and dirty way to convert the output `string` to a `int` (Double bitwise not), since you're probably not going to have negative id's for your images.

Also, [this appears to be faster](http://jsperf.com/get-id-from-string) than the `parseInt` function suggested in another answer, on Google Chrome.
Not on IE / Firefox, however, [but they've lost the lead position as most-used browsers already](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers).

Comment: I think that the readability surpasses the need for speed with this parseInt and is annihilated with the subsequent substr which could be part of the split

Comment: @mplungjan: Depends, if you're writing a specific function with as sole purpose to  parse a sting with that formatting, you're going to have to rewrite the entire function, whether you use `parseInt` or my method, any way, if the format changes. On small such pieces of code, I don't think readability (or speed for that matter), are really significant.
I can't split this on '_P', since it would then try to use the `~~` on `"100_medium.jpg"`, that won't work.

Comment: @mplungjan: Credit where it's due, man ;-)
Also, you appear to have some typo's in there.

Comment: Amended. Where is the spelling mistake? Training instead of trailing? that was fixed.

Comment: Thanks! I think that was it, yea. Personally, I'd format _P and 004_medium.jpg as `code`, though.